# Should RAII cause memory leaks?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-leaks, raii

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

struct A
{
    A(char* p)
        : p(p)
    {}

    ~A()
    {   
        delete this->p;
    }

    char* p;
};

int main()
{
    A a(new char);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

After running in debugging mode, the output window of Visual Studio 2012 shows:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{142} normal block at 0x007395A8, 1 bytes long.
 Data: < > CD 
Object dump complete.
```

What's the cause?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps it's dumping the memory leaks before the destructor is actually called? Try:

```
int main()
{
     {
         A a(new char);
     }
     _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

I suggest using the standard's (or boost's) smart pointer classes, such as `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`, instead of dealing with new/delete directly with raw pointers.

**EDIT:**
Removed the suggestion to set the pointer to `NULL`, since `delete` deals with that.

Comment: Setting a pointer to NULL in a destructor is kind of pointless.

Comment: smart pointers are not for C++ 11 only, they are also available for C++ 03

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes I realise that, but as I said, if he wants to reset what `A::p` points to, he should be checking if `p` is `NULL` before deleting and setting it to `NULL` after reseting the pointer. i.e. `if(p) delete p;`

Comment: That's also pointless, since `delete` does the correct thing with a NULL pointer i.e. nothing. It's guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @MarkRansom Wow, I actually didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You're dumping the memory before the destructor has had a chance to run, i.e. before the end of the block. Try this and see the difference:

```
int main()
{
    {
        A a(new char);
    }
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

Comment: great, looks like I copied you now :P

Comment: @miguel.martin, it would be hard to copy in 4 seconds. Great minds think alike!